# Custom Taxonomy is Missing (Or Limiting) Items

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy; "places" using toolset

region>country>city with 12 Regions / All Countries and just a few cities; 12 parents, 260 children

Where I am using the taxonomy in a post, custom post type or the menu, only some of the items show and it is quite random. 1/2 of Europe shows up 3 from the Caribbean, etc

I used the plugin Toolset; this issue has repeated in 4 different installs. I have worked with hosting and they assure me it is a development issue. I have worked with toolset and am on Day 6 of no solution; I have tried with different themes (Hello & Astra), Using Elementor or not (no plugins other than toolset itself; there is no support over the weekend. Does anyone have any idea WHY I would be missing just some of the taxonomy?

I am not seeing any errors in debugging

Comment: This probably isn't very helpful but I inherited quite a few sites where I work that were built with ToolSet and stuff like this is a common occurrence.  The support team there can be infuriating but often times the best method is to just keep after them until you finally sort through what the issue is.  My immediate guess would be that your tax queries are built in ToolSet and something is off with those queries.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for the input. The latest; if I switch out of the Gutenberg editor and use the classic editor, everything appears as normal. I see loads of issues with Gutenberg and taxonomies when researching the problem. I could go off on a raging rant right now but I'll spare everyone. I will post the final solution I get so the next person trying to perform a fundamental function like creating a taxonomy won't find themselves in a similar situation.